# Signed apk file my application for PlayStore, no maps

Tags: android, google-maps, apk

I have an application on the playstore that uses maps. Although it worked fine in debug, map doesn't appears in realease.
I did the following steps:

```
- activate maps v2 on google console
- get the API key
- paste the API key in my manifest
- export the apt file with eclipse tool to generate and sign
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happen because your given `SH1 fingerprint` signature does not match with your app's `SH1` . When you have get `API Key from API console` you enter the `SH1;package_name_of_your_app` this `SH1` is not the exact `SH1` for your APP. For this reason map is not showing.

This is happen for me also. If any thing need please ask me.

**Edited Answer**

You will get this type of thing

[image]

Comment: Do you mean there are two different SH1? One from Eclipse, one for the app?

Comment: do you have create existing keystore or new keystore at the time of export the App

Comment: if you use android default keystore then I think your app will shown , but in your case you create new keystore.

Comment: yes for this reason it will happen. please wait I will tell you the solution. This problem was happen with me . :)

Comment: @Xavier at the time of export new keystore at the end of time it will give you your app SH1 and MD5 number. Please copy this and paste this keystore to Google API Console and get API key and paste it again on your Manifest file.

Comment: I am trying this. Thank you

Comment: After your problem will be solved then please accept and +1 then answer.

Comment: I've done all that. Waiting for publication to check if it's ok.

Comment: is there a way to install signed apk to device without waiting it on play store?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44880/discussion-between-satyaki-mukherjee-and-xavier)

Comment: yes you can after export the apk you simply test the apk on your device. if this correct result then play store app also give correct result.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting in Eclipse like that, you will see a SHA1 signature for the release app. Use that one to create a new key, and add it instead. Then continue, as usual. The problem is that you have to have different keys for release and debug. Not sure where exactly was this written, but [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information) should be enough as a source I think.